# Monitoring DOM element without useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using React and in my component I would like to subscribe to position changes of a DIV. The problem is that I can't use useRef because the DIV is created by an external library, but I always know what its id is.

What can I access and subscribe to its location changes? Some advice?

Thank you

Comment: You can still use `useRef`. Try creating the ref with `null`, then in a `useEffect` assign a querySelector return to the ref's current value?

Comment: i dont think there's a way to track position without ref, above comment seems good, if you dont want to use query can wrap the component and ref assuming it takes full dimensions